# Python filecmp.cmp('old_index.html', 'new_index.html') in if event

Tags: python, file, if-statement

how can I make this python command in a if question:

```
import filecmp
filecmp.cmp('old_index.html', 'new_index.html')
```

the answer from these command is True or False.
So that I can execute something when the files are the same or when they are not.

Thanks for your help

Comment: i think you could use `bool`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use that in an `if` statement, like this

```
if filecmp.cmp('old_index.html', 'new_index.html'):
    # Do whatever you want if the files are the same
    print("Both the files are same")
else:
    # Do whatever you want if the files are NOT the same
    print("No, the files are NOT the same")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  if filecmp.cmp('old.html','new.html')==False:
  #do something like-
    print 'files are not equal'
  #same code for True value
```